# Android drag and drop: more than one view reporting a drop?

Tags: android

I seem to not be understanding Android's drag-n-drop functionality.
I have set up 4 separate Views and set their `onDragListener` to the code below.  I expect the user to drag an image onto one of the four views. When the user drops the image being dragged, I want to populate the view upon which it was dropped with related data.

The problem I am seeing is that all four views respond on `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` with `event.getResult() = true`. Only one view responds when the drag view enters the bounding area. According to the Android docs [(here)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) `event.getResult()` returns false unless ACTION_DROP was sent. But all four view show `getResult()` of true and only one shows the `ACTION_DROP` (see Logcat, below)

### Java Code

```
private OnDragListener mydragListener = new OnDragListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        ClipData dragData;
        boolean handled = false;
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {
                dragSku = event.getClipDescription().getLabel().toString();                 
                handled = true;
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_STARTED="+handled);
            } break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {

                // Report the drop/no-drop result to the user
                final boolean dropped = event.getResult();
                if (dropped) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"THIS SHOULD BE DROPPED: "+v.toString());
                    handled = true;
                }
                else {
                    handled = false;
                }

                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_ENDED="+handled);

            } break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                // Gets the item containing the dragged data
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);

                // Returns true. DragEvent.getResult() will return true.
                handled = true;

                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DROP="+handled);
            break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: {
                handled = false;

                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_EXITED="+handled);
            } break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: {
                handled = true;
                Log.d(TAG,"ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED="+handled);
            }
        }
        return handled;
    }
};
```

### LOGCAT:

```
12-10 12:13:56.240: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ClipData : ClipData { text/plain "sku340603" {T:sku} } : sku340603
12-10 12:13:56.275: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_STARTED=true
12-10 12:13:56.275: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_STARTED=true
12-10 12:13:56.275: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_STARTED=true
12-10 12:13:56.275: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_STARTED=true

12-10 12:13:56.960: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED=true
12-10 12:13:57.205: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DROP=true
12-10 12:13:57.205: I/ViewRootImpl(25667): Reporting drop result: true

12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): THIS SHOULD BE DROPPED: android.widget.ImageView@42dfa5f0
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_ENDED=true
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): THIS SHOULD BE DROPPED: android.widget.ImageView@42dee7b0
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_ENDED=true
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): THIS SHOULD BE DROPPED: android.widget.ImageView@42df7618
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_ENDED=true
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): THIS SHOULD BE DROPPED: android.widget.ImageView@42df8e48
12-10 12:13:57.215: D/BrowsePhonesDevices(25667): ACTION_DRAG_ENDED=true
```

What should `myDragListener` be doing different so that only ONE view gets a result of true from `event.getResult()`?

Comment: Really?  No one has any answers?

Comment: Just got the same problem. Will post if I figure out how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Do the update in `ACTION_DROP`.

That's where you know what was dropped (`item`, note: you can also use `getLocalState()` to pass around `Object`s), and know where it was dropped to (the first parameter of `onDrag` is the dropTarget). In case you want to know where it came from you can pass the view as local state when calling `view.startDrag(..., new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), view, 0)`.

`ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`/`ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` means:

> Hey y'all, someone started/finished a drag & drop operation (with `getResult()` result), you may now show/hide your ability to receive the drop.

You can find the official wording of the above here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#HandleEnd